# SQLite how to build DB schema for unknown column amount (multiple tables?)

Tags: java, sqlite, schema

every body:)

I have litle problem with biuld schema of my database. Imagine there is Match. You know match is between two teams. There is data of match. And there is a lot of events: goals, fouls, etc. I build one table "match" there is 3 fields: team 1 (string), team 2(string), date (long). And I want to store every event. So do I have to create for every match (for example I want to create one match per day) new table "events" and bind (put name this event's table to column as string) it to fourth field or (may be better idea) create dynamically (via Java) a lot of columns for every match? Could somebody help me? Thanks for reply :)

is it good solution in the picture? 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/p59Tr.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, lots of columns for every Match is not normalized.  This should not be done.

There are many Event rows for every Match.  What you need is a table for each and a one to many relationship.  You'll need a foreign key in the Event table to point back to its Match parent so you can JOIN them together.

You aren't going far enough, in my view.  You need Team with many Player rows.  A Foul should be assessed against a Player.  If you want to model the problem properly you need to do more work and thinking.

Lots of things to think about:

```
1 Team -> many Players
1 Player -> one Team

1 Match -> 2 Teams
1 Match -> 0 or more Goals
1 Goal -> 1 Team

1 Player -> 0 or more Goals
1 Player -> 0 or more Fouls
```

Comment: So I need one table with matches, a few tables for events (one table for one row in matche's table) and one table MATCH_EVEN table where I will connect every row (match) with event table? Yes U right with Players but I want to know simple way to slove my problem. After I will update my DB, but now I want to know how to use db...:)

Comment: You need to learn how to design a relational database properly.  Stop worrying about a "simple" way to solve your problem.  What your intuition tells you is simple might be a bad practice that has been solved a better way.  Go learn: http://people.inf.elte.hu/miiqaai/Relational%20Database%20Design%20and%20Implementation%203rd%20Edition.pdf

Comment: yes u right,  but to build more difficult db I must know how to build simple db.  tell me one thing: should I create a lot of tables each for one match or keep every events in one table.  thx

Comment: Dio you read the link I sent?  I told you how to normalize.   The database I'm recommended is not complex.  By all means put all of it into one big table.  You'll quickly learn why that's a bad idea.  I see four tables.  You are free to do whatever you wish.